# MySQL Table efficiency in web wizard

Tags: database, database-design

I'm developing an online web wizard and I got stuck on planning the database structure.

Which is more effective?

Making one table like this:

```
| ID | CLIENT | PARAM | PARAM | PARAM etc.
```

or a table with formatted parameters like this:

```
| ID | CLIENT | FORMATED_PARAMS (eg. JSON)
```

or multiple records with simple table build like this:

```
| ID | CLIENT | PARAM |
```

Structure of parameter is an array:

```
{
    "PARAM_NAME",
    "PARAM_ADDRESS_PART_1",
    "PARAM_ADDRESS_PART_2",
    "PARAM_TYPE",
    "PARAM_VALUE"
}
```

Number of parameters and their addresses are unknown so above table shouldn't contain that information. It's possible client would have permission to edit stored data so using second version might be complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating two tables:

**Client table**

```
| ID | CLIENT |
```

**Param table**

```
| ID | CLIENT_ID | PARAM_NAME | PARAM_VALUE |
       ^
       ^--- ID from Client table
```

With this structure you will be able to add endless parameters and even customize the parameters available on a per-client basis.

Welcome to [Relational Databases](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/relational-databases-for-dummies--net-30244) =)

Comment: It's close to mine first idea (3rd in question). I will also split some information to config table and will use **JOIN** to glue all together.

Thanks.

Comment: I see, I was under the impression that the Client table is going to store a unique client's basic information so that unique ID could be use to identify which params belong to which client.